# Stanford Parser : How to get a path of C's parent ---> root?

Tags: java, algorithm, stanford-nlp

This is a picture of Stanford Parser

[image: This is a picture of Stanford Parser]

I have a tree of Stanford Parser as a picture. I want get path of C'parent  -- > to root. Example : **path of "but"'parent --> root = CC S Root , or path of "it" parent --> root : PRP NP VP VP S S Root**. But I don't know how to do that. i use Stanford Parser to parsing statement .

```
        statement = "I have a dog , but I don't like it"
        Annotation document = new Annotation(statement);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document
            .get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

         for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
        List<Tree> leaves = new ArrayList<>();
        leaves = tree.getLeaves(leaves);
        for (Tree leave : leaves) {
            String compare = leave.toString();
            if(compare.equals(data.connective) == true) {


             // How to get path but --> root

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tree` has a [`parent()`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#parent--) method which returns the parent of the tree node, or `null` if none. So you should be able to do something like this inside your for loop:

```
for (Tree leave : leaves) {
    String compare = leave.toString();
    if(compare.equals(data.connective) == true) {
        Tree curr = leave;
        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.println(curr.toString());
            curr = curr.parent(); // will be null if no parent
        }
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use Tree.parent() or Tree.parent(curr) before . But output  displays error or wrong answer....

Comment: That would have been very useful information to include in your original question. What exactly have you tried and what was the output?

Comment: thank you ! It really useful . I fixed and find resolve way . Thank you :D

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it helped, you can click the arrow or checkmark next to the post to upvote or accept answers. You're also welcome to self-answer if your solution was different. That way people with a similar problem will be able to find what is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another solution.

I first used DFS to reach every node that I want and then used a method called.

- pathNodeToNode(node1, node2)

This method is from StanfordNLP tree class. Here is the method link https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html

Hope this may help someone else.